# Displaying an Image/Icon inside an EXT.NET GridPanel Cell depinding on value

Tags: ext.net

Greeting,

I need to display an image/icon AND a value in an EXT.NET cell (of a gridpanel). The value comes from the datatable. The value can either be a string ‘good’ or ‘bad’ and resides in the column ‘Status’.

For example: good accept.png or bad cancel.png.

Layout:

```
 <ext:GridPanel ID="grid" runat="server">
<Store>
   <ext:Store ID="Store1" runat="server">
            <Reader>
                <ext:ArrayReader>
                    <Fields>
                        <ext:RecordField Name="status" Mapping="Status" />
                    </Fields>
                </ext:ArrayReader>
            </Reader>
        </ext:Store>
    </Store>
 <ColumnModel ID="ColumnModel1" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <ext:Column DataIndex="status" Header="Status" Width="160">
            </ext:Column> 
        </Columns>
</ColumnModel>
</ext:GridPanel>
```

Now I have seen some exaples but I can’t seem to get the picture, I think it has something to do with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function imgRenderer(value, meta, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
if(data == ‘good’)
{
return "<img src='accept.png'/>"
}
else (data == "bad") 
        {
            return "<img src='cancel.png'/>"
        }
    }
</script>
```

More info: 
http://miamicoder.com/2009/displaying-an-image-inside-an-ext-js-gridpanel-cell-part-2/
http://techmix.net/blog/2010/11/25/add-button-to-extjs-gridpanel-cell-using-renderer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to return the value.

```
<ext:Column ColumnID="columnStatus" DataIndex="omschrijving" Header="Status" Width="150">
                <Renderer Handler="return imgRenderer(value);" />
</ext:Column>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have options, although I think there is just one minor syntax error that is causing the problem.

Option 1:

In your existing code, you should change `data` to `value`.

**Example**

```
// existing
if(data == ‘good’)

// revised
if(value == ‘good’)
```

Option 2:

Rename your images to same value as the value, although this would still require using the `value` attribute instead of `data`. Rename `accept.png` to `good.png`, and same renaming with the "bad" image. With this change you shouldn't require the if|else statement.

**Example**

```
// existing
if(data == ‘good’)
{
    return "<img src='accept.png'/>"
}
else (data == "bad") 
{
    return "<img src='cancel.png'/>"
}

// revised
return '<img src="' + value + '.png"/>';
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No luck, the grid now doesn't even show the data. Any idea where I should look?

I have added renderer handler, is this the way to go?
<ext:Column ColumnID="columnStatus" DataIndex="omschrijving" Header="Status" Width="150">
                     <Renderer Handler = "imgRenderer()" />   
                </ext:Column>